# Label doesn't transform on input focus

Tags: html, css

I want to transform a label of an input when someone clicks on the input. But it doesn't transform.

If I do `.user-input:focus, .user-input:valid` it changes the input which means it should work with the label.

```css
.user-input:focus+.user-label,
.user-input:valid+.user-label {
  color: yellow;
  transform: translate(10px, -14px) scale(.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-group">
    <label for="user" class="user-label">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="user" class="user-input" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `+` selects siblings **after** the previous selector. Your label is before the input in this example.

Comment: In css, you can only check which element is before ( by using a `+` selector), but not after. You could swap the elements in place to get that functionality for your label and swap their positions back with css, however i would recommend against it and instead use js for it.

Comment: A label's `for` attribute should refer to an ID. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **in css we can only select next sibling, we cannot select sibling that comes before selector sibling in DOM**.
- so, I have just placed `label` after `input`.
- Use below css to keep label before input in view.

```css
.input-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: start;
}
```

```css
.input-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: start;
}

.user-label {
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.user-input:active+.user-label,
.user-input:focus+.user-label,
.user-input:valid+.user-label {
  color: yellow;
  transform: translate(10px, -14px) scale(.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="user" class="user-input" required>
    <label for="user" class="user-label">Username</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that just by changing up a bit your HTML structure, switch your input with your label tag, you cannot select with css elements in the same div that are prior the targetted element

```
HTML

 <div class="container">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="user" class="user-input" required>
        <label for="user" class="user-label">Username</label>
      </div>
 </div>

CSS

.user-input:focus + .user-label {
  color: yellow;
  transform: translate(10px, -14px) scale(.8);
}
```